# Подсчитать строки в таблице за исключением строк из правой таблицы?

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(LogId) as CNT FROM log
            LEFT JOIN subscrubetousers ON subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersType = log.LogType
            RIGHT JOIN userlog ul ON ul.userlogIdLog = log.LogId WHERE subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser = 7
```

Нужно подсчитать количество строк в таблице **log**, ID которых нет в таблице **userlog** для заданного пользователя.
Почему-то **RIGHT JOIN** не работает так, как планировал.

Можно поступить через LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM log
            LEFT JOIN subscrubetousers ON subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersType = log.LogType
            LEFT OUTER JOIN userlog ul ON log.LogId = ul.userlogIdLog WHERE ul.userlogIdLog IS NULL AND subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersIdUser = 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во второй запрос добавь `SELECT COUNT(*)`, и он выведет требуемое кол-во записей.
В `WHERE` уже есть условие `ul.userlogIdLog IS NULL`. Это и будет кол-во записей, в `log` которых нет в `userlog`.